# Move enemy to player's new position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

In the code below I move the player to a tile that the player touches, and then what I expect to happen is also move the enemy to the player's new position. What actually happens is the enemy moves to the tile that the player was on before moving. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to get my desired result??

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var player: SKSpriteNode!
var enemy: SKSpriteNode!
var grid: SKTileMapNode!

var turnState: String = "pause"

var touchLocation: CGPoint = .zero

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    loadSceneNodes()
}

func loadSceneNodes() {
    setupGrid()
    setupCharacter()
    setupEnemy()
}

func setupGrid() {
    let columns = 10
    let rows = 10
    let size = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)

    guard let tileSet = SKTileSet(named: "Ground Tiles") else {
        fatalError("Tile set not found")
    }

    grid = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet, columns: columns, rows: rows, tileSize: size)
    addChild(grid)

    grid.name = "grid"

    let tileGroups = tileSet.tileGroups

    guard let dirtLightTile = tileGroups.first(where: {$0.name == "DirtLight Tile"}) else {
        fatalError("No DirtLight tile definition found")
    }

    guard let dirtDarkTile = tileGroups.first(where: {$0.name == "DirtDark Tile"}) else {
        fatalError("No DirtDark tile definition found")
    }

    for column in 0...columns {
        for row in 0...rows {
            if (row % 2 == 0) && (column % 2 == 0) {
                grid.setTileGroup(dirtLightTile, forColumn: column, row: row)
            } else if (row % 2 != 0) && (column % 2 != 0) {
                grid.setTileGroup(dirtLightTile, forColumn: column, row: row)
            } else {
                grid.setTileGroup(dirtDarkTile, forColumn: column, row: row)
            }
        }
    }
}

func setupCharacter() {
    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "knight")
    let height = player.size.height
    let scaleFactor = grid.tileSize.height / height
    player.setScale(scaleFactor)
    player.position = grid.centerOfTile(atColumn: 0, row: 0)
    addChild(player)
}

func setupEnemy() {
    enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "knight")
    let height = enemy.size.height
    let scaleFactor = grid.tileSize.height / height
    enemy.setScale(scaleFactor)
    enemy.position = grid.centerOfTile(atColumn: 9, row: 9)
    addChild(enemy)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: touchLocation)
    for node in touchedNodes {
        if node.name == "grid" {
            touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            turnState = "player"
        }
    }

    print("touch location: (row: \(grid.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: touchLocation)), column: \(grid.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: touchLocation)))")
    print("player current position: \(getRowCol(character: player))")
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    switch turnState {
    case "player":
        print("moving player")
        movePlayer()
        turnState = "enemy"
        print("finished moving player")
    case "enemy":
        print("moving enemy")
        moveEnemy()
        turnState = "pause"
        print("finished moving enemy")
    default:
        return
    }

    print("frame finished")
}


func movePlayer() {

    let touchRow = grid.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: touchLocation)
    let touchCol = grid.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: touchLocation)

    print("moving player to: (row: \(touchRow), column: \(touchCol))")

    let newTile = grid.centerOfTile(atColumn: touchCol, row: touchRow)
    let move = SKAction.move(to: newTile, duration: 0.5)
    player.run(move)

}

func moveEnemy() {
    let playerRow = getRowCol(character: player).row
    let playerCol = getRowCol(character: player).column

    print("moving enemy to: (row: \(playerRow), column: \(playerCol))")

    let newTile = grid.centerOfTile(atColumn: playerCol, row: playerRow)
    let move = SKAction.move(to: newTile, duration: 0.5)
    enemy.run(move)
}


func getRowCol(character: SKSpriteNode) -> (row: Int, column: Int) {
    let row = grid.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: character.position)
    let col = grid.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: character.position)

    return (row, col)

    }
}
```

output below when clicking on tile (row: 0, column: 1):

```
touch location: (row: 0, column: 1)
player current position: (row: 0, column: 0)
moving player
moving player to: (row: 0, column: 1)
finished moving player
frame finished
moving enemy
moving enemy to: (row: 0, column: 0)
finished moving enemy
frame finished
```

Comment: Can you post the 'run' method

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the 'run' method. I have edited my post to include all of the code in my GameScene file. Movement of the characters is initiated by the user touching a tile.

Comment: So I have discovered that if in movePlayer() I replace player.run(move) with player.position = newTile, everything works fine except the player's movement is not animated.